# Counting based on criterias in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `DataFrame` like this:

```
d={'gen':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D'], 'diff':pd.Series([1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1], index=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17])}
wk = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18])
```

my goal is to count how many occurences the `gen` have based on `diff` with some criterias:

1. Count if `diff` is 1, and
2. `gen` at index `i` equal to `gen` at index `i+1`, and
3. If there's a consecutive 1's, then the count will be like this: if (number of consecutive 1) %2 == 0: count = number of consecutive/2, if not: count = (number of consecutive - 1) /2

with this code, I can achieve what I want:

```
k=0
j=0
z={}
for i in range(wk.shape[0]):
    if wk['diff'][i] == 1:
        if wk['gen'][i] == wk['gen'][i+1]:
            if j == 0:
                j+=2
            if j%2==0:
                k+=1                
            if j>=2:
                j+=1
            z[wk['gen'][i]] = k
        if wk['gen'][i] != wk['gen'][i+1]:
            j=0
            k=0
```

and the result of dictionary `z` is: `{'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'D': 4}`

but when I used a bigger data (more than 410,000 records), the counter didn't always start from 0 when the `gen` at index `i` is not equal to `gen` at index `i+1`. The data I used is: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ijAz71zIDmNlnrlgrgAARxjGlZcQAFk5/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115800565047656326025&rtpof=true&sd=true)
what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the third criteria? It is not clear to me.

Comment: if the sequence of 1's is like this (the 'gen' are same): 1,1,1 it counts just 1, but if the sequence is 1,1,1,1, the count is 2.

Comment: Shouldn't D have a count of 3? 4 consecutive 1s, and 3 consecutive 1s should sum to 2+1, no?

Comment: Shouldn't also A have a final value of 1 since there are only 3 As that satisfy all rules? The fourth A should not be considered because `gen[i+1] = B`.

Comment: @BrenerRamos `A` have final value of 2 since the first and third 1 is counted. (the sequence **1**, 1, **1**, 1, the bold one is counted)

Comment: @mozway yes you're right and I missed a special case where the last four rows of the data is like this for `gen`: `D, D, D, D` and the 'diff': `1, 1, 1, NaN`, it will count 2, because there's two pair of D with `diff` of 1 between them. Then, `D` at index 9 and 11 is counted, the final value of `D` is 2+2=4

Comment: @dzdws do you mean that the NaN should be handled as a 1? Then my solution would work if you use `wk.groupby('gen')['diff'].ffill()` in place of `wk['diff']`

Comment: @mozway yes, if the case is the last two `gen` are same, in the previous case is `D, D`. But when I try your new solution, the value of `D` is still 3

Answer (score 1):

Count the consecutive 1s per group with [`groupby.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html), perform a [`floordiv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.floordiv.html) by 2 (equivalent to your `x/2 if x%2==0 else (x-1)/2`), and aggregate again with [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) before converting [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
group = wk['diff'].ne(wk.groupby('gen')['diff'].shift()).cumsum()
m = wk['diff'].eq(1)

out = (wk[m].groupby(['gen', group])      # keep only 1s and group
             ['diff'].count().floordiv(2) # count and floor division
            .groupby(level='gen').sum()   # sum per "gen" group
            .loc[lambda x: x>0].to_dict() # only counts > 0 and convert to dict
      )
```

Output:

```
{'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'D': 3}
```

###### Intermediates

`group` and `m`:

```
   gen  diff  group      m
0    A   1.0      1   True
1    A   1.0      1   True
2    A   1.0      1   True
3    A   1.0      1   True
4    B   2.0      2  False
5    B   1.0      3   True
6    B   1.0      3   True
7    B   1.0      3   True
8    C   1.0      4   True
9    D   1.0      5   True
10   D   1.0      5   True
11   D   1.0      5   True
12   D   1.0      5   True
13   D   2.0      6  False
14   D   2.0      6  False
15   D   1.0      7   True
16   D   1.0      7   True
17   D   1.0      7   True
18   D   NaN      8  False
```